# how to config golang glide?

Tags: go, svn, glide-golang

my svn client checkout project from svn server need user and passwords,
how to config  glide ?
the glide.yaml content:

```
- package: xxx.net/project-dir
  vcs:     svn
  repo:    svn://xxx.net/project-dir
```

execute "glide install"
report:
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
: exit status 1

Comment: Does it work if you include auth info in repo URL? E.g. `svn://username:password@xxx.net/project-dir`? Or svn over ssh: `svn+ssh://username:password@xxx.net/project-dir`?